# What was the first compiler/interpreter/assembler to indicate problematic columns in diagnostic messages?

Tags: history, programming, compilers

These days, most compilers and interpreters seem to provide the following in diagnostics:

- A description of the problem
- The name of the source file
- A line number
- A relevant position within the line
- The text of the line
- An indication of where the relevant position is in the line's text

In earlier systems, diagnostic printouts often consisted, from what I can tell, of a message
or error code and the text of an offending card or line. All that is really missing is the
precise indication of where on the card or line the problem was found.

I was somewhat surprised to see that the Pascal P-series of compilers, as far back as
[P2](http://www.moorecad.com/standardpascal/p2.html) from 1974, provided almost everything
that modern systems do:

- An error code
- A line number
- The text of the line (albeit as a side effect of listing the source code)
- An indication of where the relevant position is in the line's text

(See the routines [`error`](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Esteven/pascal/book/pcom.html#p338)
and [`endofline`](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Esteven/pascal/book/pcom.html#p303). The file
name was implicit, since only one file was ever being compiled.)

Did any systems predating P2 do this (or better, e.g. by indicating a range of
positions as in GCC and Clang)? LISP 1.5 seems to have been close, having a function `error1`
that was designed for this exact purpose (printing a line of text along with a “cursor”),
although the interpreter never actually used it!

Comment: It might be worth to keep in mind that a good error description is usually way more helpful. This is especially true with classic languages like Assembler, COBOL or FORTRAN, were each line was always a single statement. Only free form languages (essentially all ALGOL descendants) gain from having a column noted, as a line could have more than one statement, making assignment of a specific message to each hard.

Comment: For a contrary opinion: [SNOBOL4](http://worrydream.com/refs/Griswold-TheSnobolProgrammingLanguage.pdf) was a one statement per line (card-oriented) language, and its authors found it useful to indicate the offending column (by mean of a mark in the appropriate place under the listed source line).  See page 175 in the linked document.  Of course, some people might consider SNOBOL4 to be more-or-less syntax-free :-)

Comment: @Raffzahn  "Only free form languages gain from having a column noted" Not when a single-line Fortran statement contained 10 pairs of parentheses - or rather, it should have contain them, but didn't.

Comment: @alephzero True, but only (somewhat) useful if they are _non nested_ pairs in _10 different_ expressions. As soon as they share the same expression, the compiler might only point at the end of that whole expression - not really useful, or is it?

Comment: @Raffzahn: COBOL formally allows multiple statements on one line with a few exclusions, although given the verbose style it encourages and sometimes requires, relatively few pairs of complete statements fit in the 61 chars traditionally available in Area B (this is now increased). And if/when you couldn't do it in most cases, people often like(d) to be consistent and never do it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Cool. To be honest, in all the years I was forced to do COBOL (usually for interface purpose) I never seen that feature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Printing a mere column number seems like a step backwards.   The Whetstone Algol compiler (1963, if memory serves) told you the line number and delimiter that were problematic, as well as (of course) an error code and the line in question.

```
FAIL 133
LINE   6    
DELIMITER [̲
IDENTIFIER writetex
BECAUSE OF LINE   2
```

Underlined bracket, shown as 2 separate characters on modern ASCII equipment but not on the contemporaneous Flexowriter, was a string quote in this Algol dialect.

Error 133 means we ran off the end of the program text at line 6, in this case because of a missing closing string quote.  The opening string quote was on line 2, just after the identifier `writetext` (this dialect considered only 8 characters to be significant).

So, my answer to the question is another question – didn't they always do this?  (Depends on implementation, of course, and how much attention was paid to diagnostics. The Walgol guys were pretty keen on diagnosability).

---

KDF9 was oriented to paper tape rather than cards, and paper tape people don't really think in terms of column numbers, so a raw column number wouldn't have really helped anyway.  On the other hand, converting "column N" to N−1 spaces and an up-arrow on the listing, underneath the listing of the offending line, is decidedly better.

SNOBOL4, developed in the early 1960s at Bell Labs, initially on IBM System/360, used that particular technique.

[Section 10.1.5 in *The SNOBOL4 programming language*](http://worrydream.com/refs/Griswold-TheSnobolProgrammingLanguage.pdf), the definitive description of SNOBOL4, shows that the error indicator was a (vertical) apostrophe.  Likely that particular listing was from SNOBOL on an S/360.

```
X = A+B
    '  
*** ILLEGAL CHARACTER IN EXPRESSION
```

(Operators needed to be offset by spaces or other delimiters)

At the time SNOBOL4 was developed, it was very much a card-oriented language, though it had no particular column requirements except for column 1 having special meaning (labels and comments), and of course a 72-columm limit.

This example shows that error-location to a column was already a known technique in the 1960s, though of course this is the 'pointer in column' approach rather than 'print column N' approach.

---

(I removed the FORTRAN example, since although it demonstrated a good level of error diagnosis, it's not really relevant to the point of location by specific column).

Comment: Well, I guess like so many, it's a solution which, like any other needs a problem to be useful. With languages like Assembler, FORTRAN or COBOL, it's way more useful (like shown in the second example) to give a fine worded description.

Comment: @Raffzahn -  I updated my answer: printing "column N" is not so useful, but using that to place an uparrow on the listing is much more so.

Comment: This answer brings up some interesting points I hadn't thought of. The Walgol example reminds me of [Perl's error handling for multi-line strings](http://jeffreykegler.github.io/Ocean-of-Awareness-blog/individual/2011/01/perl-and-parsing-6-error-handling.html). Here is how GCC reports a similar error in a C program: https://godbolt.org/z/W4jecv6Wb.

Comment: @another-dave To be fair, with the source code on punched cards, "column N" was as good as an uparrow. Finding "N" among the column numbers between rows 0 and 1 on the card and looking up  to the printed text: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card#/media/File:FortranCardPROJ039.agr.jpg is easy.

Comment: @LeoB - maybe, but for understanding the error, seeing clear indication on the line printer listing is better.  Isn't the existence of listings evidence that it's easier than reading the cards?  (I agree that ultimately I have to find the erroneous card to replace it).

Comment: @another-dave Erm, my point was about your FORTRAN example. After already saying "THE CLOSING PARENTHESIS IS NOT FOLLOWED BY A COMMA", pointing out a column doesn't add much help. In contrast Algol _is_ a language were pointing out the column _may_ be helpful, _if_ there are multiple statements on a line.

Comment: @another-dave Regarding printing a mark below a faulty line: Not sure how it was handled in your job, but we did usually order only the error list to be delivered, but no full listing. Less paper, faster round trip time. A full listing was only done when the existing had to many pencil marks or after some days.

Comment: I never had a 'job' that used punched cards (except to the extent I had to provide card input for an RJE emulator), though I did use cards as a high-school student (round trip by GPO = 3 days) and as a university student (but then it was mostly initial input on cards, edit online - cards were cheaper on the funny-money budget).  I understand the infrequent listings approach, but I probably only got paper listings after removing the assembler/compiler errors online.  But in your case - didn't the "error listing" include the source line?

Comment: @Raffzahn - yeah, in retrospect, the subject of the question is error location to a column, and the fortran example does not show that).  Removed that.  Added Snobol.

Comment: @another-dave NOOO. That was a extreme to the point example making that the idea of 'pointing to a column' in itself might not be an improvement at all. I would see this as a very important addition - it was in fact, why I upvoted that answer - it gives a more in depth answer than just pointing to some language and year. It's about understanding the topic.

Comment: @another-dave Regardin 'getting the line as well in error listing' That usually depends on compiler and more so listing (error level) type.  I usually went with the shortest possible form, so line number and an error description (but that one as deep as possible). And of course, experience in a school environment may be quite different than on a job, were you do that kind of work full time for a long time. Which usually included round trip times of just a few minutes, as one put in the job and went for the printer to collect the paper in one turn